# Sed script to remove word-break character

Tags: bash, shell, sed

We have a situation where long text lines are broken into multiple lines with the `=` character.  I thought a simple sed script like `sed 's/=$//g' old-file > new-file` (or `sed 's/\=$//g' old-file > new-file`) would fix the issue.  However, this sed command is just not recombining the broken-up text lines the way I was expecting.

For example, if the contents of old-file are:

```
I wonder who came up with the phrase A qu=
ick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

I would like the contents of the new-file to be:

```
I wonder who came up with the phrase A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

---

Q) What is the best way to remove a trailing character from a line of text, if that character indicates that it is a word-break character?

Comment: You also need to remove the newline after the `=`.

Comment: `this sed command is just not recombining the broken-up text lines the way I was expecting` Please explain then in what way were you expecting it to "recombine the broken-up text lines"(??)? Please post some example input and some output you would like to have.

Comment: @KamilCuk, I have provided the example that you requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` works on single lines. It loads *one line* to memory at each cycle. To load more, you have to use `sed` commands to do that.

With GNU sed and enough memory you can replace the `=` **and  a newline after it**:

```
sed -z 's/=\n//'
```

Otherwise you have to append the next line to pattern space. Loop until a `=` on the end is found, I think with:

```
sed ': again; /=$/{ s///;N;s/\n//;b again; }'
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `sed ': again; /=$/{ N; s/=\n//; t again}'`?

Comment: Would also work. I do not like `t` - your code will work the same with `b again`. I guess I didn't want to repeat `=` pattern twice, so used `s////`

Comment: One substitution vs two; I'd rather have one and retype the `=`. --- Come to think of it, `t` lets you move the label inside inside the brackets, which is a bit nicer looking: `sed '/=$/{ :a; N; s/=\n//; t a }'`

Comment: `I'd rather have one and retype the =` When patterns are stored in variable, it's sometimes easier in long scripts if they are listed in `sed` sources once in case of refactoring. I typically do: `sed '/'"$var"'/{ s///; ....`. `t lets you move` yes, but it's behavior is counterintuitive with multiple `s` commands. If _any_ of the `s` commands in current cycle succeed, then `t` jumps. It always messes up in longer `sed` scripts with multiple `s` commands. `which is a bit nicer lookin` exactly, that will not work in case of multiple `=\n` patterns in file. ex. `'a=\nb\nc=\nd'`

Comment: Like `sed '/=$/{ :a; N; s/=\n//; t a }'` really shows why `t` is wrong. `t` jumps one too many times, on the last line where `s/=\n//` failed, then `t` will jump to `a`, because __any__ of the previous `s` commands succeeded in current cycle. Then it will read one too many lines and quit after the next line, because the last `t` in current cycle failed. Ie. `t` _is not_ `if`. Try `echo -e 'a=\nb\nc=\nd' | sed '/=$/{ :a; N; s/=\n//; t a }'` (well, unless in this case OP does not care, he has only one long line, then it's fine,  but I think not).

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;N;s/=\n//;ta;P;D' file
```

Open a two line window throughout the length of the file.

If the first line ends in `=` delete it and the newline and repeat.

Otherwise, print then delete the first line and repeat.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `awk` solution is to set the Record Separator to `=\n`, Output Record Separator to empty, and print.

```
awk -v RS="=\n" -v ORS="" '1' file
```

or

```
awk 'BEGIN{ RS="=\n"; ORS="" } 1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat old-file | tr '-' ' ' > new-file
```

I deliberately use dashes as tr anchors for carriage returns; tr is the only utility I know of which easily lets me insert them.  It is difficult for just about every other tool to my knowledge.  It can be done with ed, but not gracefully.

```
cat oldfile | tr '-' '\n' > newfile
```

It is very useful to be able to split lines, because line numbers are much easier to work with than regular expressions.  I can use ed to get individual line numbers, and relative (+/-*number)* addressing in ed means I can still climb up and down files and do blind line-by-line searching, even if I don't know the exact number of what I want, and if making a multiple pattern regex for the whole file is too hard.

Comment: `echo old-file`? You want the contents of the file, not the name...

Comment: True.  I'm tired; and now that I've replaced it with cat, I will have people complaining about spaces or whatever else because I didn't use read.

Comment: Input redirection, not Useless Use Of Cat! `tr '-' ' ' < old-file > new-file` (Also not sure how replacing hyphens with spaces  or newlines will do what OP wants...)

Comment: "We have a situation where long text lines are broken into multiple lines with the = character."

His words.  Replacing '=' (or the carriage return immediately before it) with spaces, would rejoin the lines.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I searched for some hours and tried doing it with regex, but got a frustrated and went to binary level:

`cat file | xxd -p | sed 's/3d0a//g' | xxd -p -r`

Resulting script: (I know it's not the proper usage of printf, fixing that

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line; do
  DATASTREAM=`printf '%s\n' "$line"`
  STRING_DATA=`echo "$STRING_DATA\n$DATASTREAM"`
done

echo -e `echo $STRING_DATA | xxd -p | sed 's/3d0a//g' | xxd -p -r`
```